# Speed up data logging code

Tags: c++

I have a device that outputs 64 bits of binary data at a rate of 1KHz. I am reading the device over USB via a 3rd party DLL, converting the binary data into a float, timestamping it, and writing to file.

I have the following setup at the moment:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    unsigned char Message_Rx[64];
    USHORT Bytes_Read=0;
    std::ofstream out(argv[1]);

    do
    {
        Result = Comms.USBRead(&Message_Rx[0],&Bytes_Read);
        unsigned long now = getTickCount(start);
        if(Result != 0)
        {

            uint16_t msb (Message_Rx[11] & 0xff) \\leftshited 8;
            uint16_t lsb (Message_Rx[12] & 0xff);
            uint16_t rate = msb | lsb;
            char outstring[1024];
            sprintf(outstring, "%d\t%.7f", now, (float)rate*0.03125);
            out << outstring << "\n";
        }

    }while(!kbhit());

    out.close();

}
```

(Sorry, formatting gets messed up with `>>` or `<<`).

This produces perfectly good results on my desktop. There doesn't appear to be any data missing and the timestamps are continuous and 1ms apart.

```
143379582   -0.5937500
143379583   -1.5312500
143379584   -1.6250000
143379585   -1.4062500
143379586   -1.1875000
143379587   -1.3437500
143379588   -1.3125000
143379589   -1.3125000
143379590   -1.1562500
```

But when I run this on the old laptop that I need to use I get timestamps that appear in blocks and it looks like there must be some data missing:

```
143379582   -0.5937500
143379582   -1.5312500
143379582   -1.6250000
143379582   -1.4062500
143379582   -1.1875000
143379593   -1.3437500
143379593   -1.3125000
143379593   -1.3125000
143379593   -1.1562500
```

Is there a way to achieve a speedup of my code so that I won't lose data?

Comment: please paste valid code. Comments in C++ are started with `//`, not ` \\ `.

Comment: My first guess would be that everything is fine, and `getTickCount()` is the culprit. The 11ms gap you see is a typical gap for low-res system timers. The thing that changed is probably the `getTickCount()` implementation, which is low-res on the old laptop.

Comment: Thinking a bit more, it is unlikely that you will be able to reliably get the data every real-time millisecond with a non-RT OS. You new PC may be able, but a single core old laptop may not be. That doesn't mean you don't get the data reliably, just that the data will be read from a system buffer (usually 4KB for comm, so large enough), so you may get 11 samples every 11ms.

Answer (score 1):

To say this loud and clear: for any PC that is not a Intel 486SX, 64kb/s is a utmost laughable rate. Getting a few Mb/s over USB is very doable with small, Dollar-a-piece microcontrollers without any optimization.
 Whatever goes wrong needs investigation much more than your code does.

I don't know the `Comms` library, but that's where I'd look for the place where time is spent.

Other than that, your printing stuff to the screen should take orders of magnitude more time than your processing, but still shouldn't be a problem. As mentioned, 1kS/s * 64 b/S is *nothing* for modern (read: last twenty years) PC hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend storing the raw data until the key is hit.  After the key is pressed, output the data.

You want to remove formatting and output from high performance code areas.

Paraphrasing a song, *There will be time enough for printing when the data's done*.

**Edit 1:**
An array-based circular queue is a good data structure to hold the incoming data.  This gives you the last *N* data samples.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have issues with performance, your first step should be to profile the code to see what parts of it are taking up time.

However, for your code, I would say that the printing and string handling are unnecessary for the main loop.  I would have a separate array of timestamps and within my main loop only acquire data.

After a key is hit, you no longer have timing restrictions and can deal with the somewhat expensive operation of file I/O and building up of the strings.

A final note is that your OS might be stealing CPU cycles from you.  You may want to try to run your code with higher priorities to rule out scheduling.

With all that said, as was mentioned above, your data rate should be sustainable unless you're running on some really vintage hardware.